# Column values as factorial in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence, factorial

I have created a trigger, that will autoincrement the id, according to the sequence, every time a new record is inserted. Like this:

```
create sequence test_seq 
start with 1 
increment by 1 
nomaxvalue; 

--drop trigger test_trigger;
create or replace trigger test_trigger
before insert on myTable
for each row
begin
select test_seq.nextval into :new.tab_id from dual;
end;
```

However, I'd like to insert a factorial of the row index instead. How could I achieve this?

Edit:

```
create or replace trigger test_trigger
after insert on myT
for each row
begin
select fac(test_seq.nextval) into :new.tab_id from dual;
end;
```

Added fac function which works fine:

```
create or replace function fac(n in number)

return number

is
     v number :=1;
begin
     for i in  1..n
loop
     v :=v * i;
end loop;
     return v;
```

end;

But I still only see 1,2,3,4 in the table instead of 1,2,6,24...

Comment: Then you have to make a factorial function at other palce. then pass the value of sequence of into this function and returned value will be assigned into the newid var and then inserted into the table.

Comment: You need to drop the `BEFORE` trigger and change the `AFTER` trigger (with the factorial function) to a `BEFORE` trigger. Doing this: `select fac(test_seq.nextval) into :new.tab_id from dual;` in an `AFTER` trigger doesn't actually set the value for the newly-inserted column.

Answer (score 0):

[From Oracle's documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) You want to use a `BEFORE` trigger in this instance, an `AFTER` trigger won't actually change the table's data just from setting it in `NEW`:

> Because the trigger uses the BEFORE keyword, it can access the new
>   values before they go into the table, and can change the values if
>   there is an easily-corrected error by assigning to :NEW.column_name.

My guess is that you are still seeing the same old values from the sequence because your `BEFORE` trigger still exists; the `AFTER` trigger won't change those values.

So what you want is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON myt
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT FAC(test_seq.nextval) INTO :new.tab_id FROM dual;
END;
/
```

I think as of Oracle 11g (or maybe it's 10g; can't remember) you can also do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON myt
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.tab_id := FAC(test_seq.nextval);
END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like

```
create function factorial (n integer) return integer as
  ...

create or replace trigger test_trigger
 after insert on mytable
 -- don't do this for each row
begin
  update mytable set 
    tab_id = factorial((select count(*) from mytable))
  where tab_id is null;
end;
/
```

Comment: why where tab_is null?

Comment: Because you need to calculate it once

Comment: There's no good reason to update the table from a trigger on the same table.

Comment: True, there is no good reason to do that. But that's what happens when you use an `AFTER` trigger where a `BEFORE` trigger is more appropriate.